# Get value from textfield and pass as parameter to MySQL Stored Procedure in yii

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, yii

I'm new with programming in Yii..I have a textfield in views/_form and i want to get the entered value in textbox to be sent as parameter to a MySQL stored procedure.

```
<div class="form">
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
'id'=>'usercredentials-form',
// Please note: When you enable ajax validation, make sure the corresponding
// controller action is handling ajax validation correctly.
// There is a call to performAjaxValidation() commented in generated controller code.
// See class documentation of CActiveForm for details on this.
'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
)); ?>

<p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'userCredentialsEmail'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'userCredentialsEmail',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>128)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'userCredentialsEmail'); ?>
</div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div><!-- form -->
```

I want to get Email entered by user to be sent as parameter to the MySQL stored procedure insert_usercred.Please Help..

**EDIT**

This is my Usercredntialscontroller.php/actionCreate()

```
public function actionCreate()
{

    $model=new Usercredentials;
    $userid=Userportfolio::model()->findByPk($model->iduserCredentials);


    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);



    if(isset($_POST['Usercredentials'])
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Usercredentials'];


         echo $userCredentialsEmail = $_POST["Usercredentials"]["userCredentialsEmail"];


        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->iduserCredentials));
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
        ));
}
```

**EDIT**

This is what i've done to execute the stored procedure

```
if(isset($_POST['Usercredentials'))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Usercredentials'];
        echo $userCredentialsEmail = $_POST["Usercredentials"]["userCredentialsEmail"];
        $command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('call executeInsert($userCredentialsEmail)');
        if($command->execute())
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->iduserCredentials));
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
        '
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atlast i found the answer

A value from textbox can be obtained like this

```
$userCredentialsEmail = $_POST["MODEL_CLASS_NAME"]["userCredentialsEmail"]
```

it can be passed as parameter to a stored procedure like this

```
$command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("call executeInsert('$userCredentialsEmail')");
```

and can be executed like this

```
$command->execute();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the text field name as

```
   echo $userCredentialsEmail = $_POST["MODEL_CLASS_NAME"]["userCredentialsEmail"]
```

To call Stored procedure,

```
$command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("call my_proc($userCredentialsEmail)");
$command->execute();
```

Refer this yii forum:

http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/28134-stored-procedure-out-parameter/

Comment: Thanks for ur answer @kumar_v.But how can i pass this value to my stored procedure in Yii..

Comment: ok i have edited my question..I want to execute a stored procedure with `userCredentialsEmail` as parameter @kumar_v

Comment: I asked you to add coding for calling stored procedure.

Comment: Actually i dont know how to call a stored procedure in yii..i'm very new to yii.. @kumar_v

Comment: sorry..Cdb Exception --CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054

Comment: without seeing your code, how can i answer? sorry i can't continue.. you have to try something from your side even you are new. You have to try yourself.

Comment: I've edited my question with what i've done now(after seeing ur answer).. @kumar_v